# Jquery : binding a function to a click event of an element already bound

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click

There's a first binding done on the click event of an element :

```
$("#element").on("click", function() {
      //actions of function1
});
```

I would like to be able to bind another function to it, preserving the actions of the precedent function. Something like :

```
    function elementClickAdd(elementId,newFunction){

       //here, get the actions of function1

        $("#"+elementId).on('click', function() {
           //perform actions of function1
           newFunction();
        });
    }
```

But I can't figure out how to make this.

Could you help me please ?

Thanks

Edit : thanks for helping, the solution is here : https://jsfiddle.net/9bo6dvmb/1/ enjoy :)

Comment: you can just add the new one, and the first one will run before the 2nd, unless the first cancels it.

Answer (score 0):

If you creating the id dynamically, you can call the event after generating only, so write this line after appending the ID. Like below

```js
function dynamic_bind()
    {
      $("#test").append("<div id='tt'>test example</div>");
    
      $("#tt").on("click",function(){
        hi();  
       });    
    }

function hi()
{
  alert("executed");
  
}

dynamic_bind();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">Sample Div</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it seems I expressed myself wrong. It's not about creating an id dynamically. But about getting access to an "already bound function" to the click event. Getting access of this function, to add some actions on it.

Comment: Can you give more details, or enter your code on jsfiddle